# Is there a vegan Durian pie recipe?

Tags: veganism, cooking, recipe-request

I have been able to find quite a few Durian pie recipes, but they all seem to contain some ***animal products*** such as ***cream***.

I was wondering if there is a vegan Durian pie recipe somewhere out there that I just haven't been able to find yet?

*(By answering this question you are supporting a good cause: you are stopping me from experimenting myself and stinking out the whole neighbourhood (I would probably just try shoving Durian in the bread machine)! They will thank you greatly!)*

Comment: Most dairy or other animal products have a suitable alternative; in your example, you can substitute coconut cream for the dairy cream, etc

Comment: @nadavvadan: That is a good point! I didn't think of that! I would still be interested though in a purely Vegan one in the sense that it doesn't even need these alternatives, but if there isn't anything like that, then a recipe where we know that the alternative definitely works (as it can sometimes go wrong). As I am baking a pie for a chef and I don't want to get it terribly wrong!

Comment: How can anyone stand the stench of baking durian?

Comment: Perhaps you know my plan is in fact on weaponising it. ;)

Comment: " I would still be interested though in a purely Vegan one in the sense that it doesn't even need these alternatives"  That sounds ideological rather than well considered.  If something has no animal products it already is "purely vegan" even if it is substituting for dairy.

If we followed your logic, then we couldn't wear cotton as it is a substitute for wool.  In fact we couldn't eat anything as it could be seen as a substitute for meat.

Comment: @Steve: Yes, you're right. Just give me a nice Vegan Durian Pie recipe please then! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, here is [an example of a vegan durian pie recipe](http://mochachocolatarita.blogspot.com/2010/06/baked-durian-in-whole-wheat-filo-pastry.html).

Essentially it is:

> - Preheat oven to 350F/180C.
> - Lightly grease a baking dish, lay a couple
>     layers of filo pastry sheets, brushing in between with peanut oil (you
>     can use butter if you want more oomph), tuck them in as you would do
>     pastry base for a pie.
> - Then simply add durian flesh to fill the pastry
>     "bowl" and top it with a thin layer of caster sugar to get the
>     "bruleed" effect.
> - Don't forget to brush the top layer of filo pastry
>     with some oil/butter to make it gloriously golden.